# Can stroke-width on a SVG be animated?

Tags: svg, width, stroke

I tried to animate the width of a SVG like this and it did not work

Normally I can have multiple lines, but can I make them thicker/thinner?

```
.swidth {
  animation: hideshow 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes hideshow {
  from { stroke-width="2"; }
  to { stroke-width="6;"; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about CSS3 animation browser support, but if that were to work you would have to change `stroke-width="2";` to `stroke-width: 2`;

Answer (score 3):

It's CSS syntax inside @keyframes so something like:

```
@keyframes hideshow {
  from { stroke-width: 2; }
  to { stroke-width: 6; }
}
```